# All assemblies are not getting copied in test result - MS test

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mstest

Hi I am using MS test for unit testing. 
I have some references in test project which are not refer directly.
when ms test create test result folder it copies only dll which are used in test. If I initialize reference assembly in test initialize it work.

But is there any other way to copy all assemblies in test result folder or is there ant way to run test without even creating test result.

Thank you :)

Comment: Only MsTest uses the Test result folder. If you use NUnit or MBUnit you don't have to worry about it. Instead it runs from the output folder of the test project

Comment: Thanks for reply :) yes it works with Nunit even if I use resharper it works with some setting. but I am using ms test for some reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the TestSettings, add the required files to the Deployment Items. Also, check the properties on the reference and ensure it is set to 'Copy to output folder'.

The related question: [How can I get "Copy to Output Directory" to work with Unit Tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227545/how-can-i-get-copy-to-output-directory-to-work-with-unit-tests?rq=1) has the details.